# Nested promise in .then running before 1st promise node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise, es6-promise

I'm having a problem with my program at the moment in which I am running a promise in the .then of a promise, however it is running the 2nd promise before the first. This is not what I want since it relies on the 1st promise to work. Here is my code (The console.logs are random, but I just came up with stuff on the spot for checking when things run)

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        var query = {
            class: result[`class${i}`]
        };
        dbo.collection("homeworks").find(query).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                current = current + 1;
                console.log(current)
                allhomework[current] = result[i];
                console.log(allhomework[current])
            }
            db.close();

        });
    }
    console.log("HOLA");
    resolve(allhomework);
})
.then((allhomework) => {
    console.log("HOLA MIS AMIGOS")
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("v");
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            console.log("uaefshiudvhofdh")
            console.log(allhomework[1]);
        }
        resolve();
    }).then(() => {
        response.render('index', {
            username: req.session.user,
            homeworks: allhomework
        });
    })

})
.catch(console.log)
```

Comment: The first thing to do is format the code in a consistent, readable way -- that will help you, and it'll help us help you.

Comment: The obvious issue is that you are immediately resolving the first promise, without ever waiting for any of those queries you started in the loop.

Comment: Try putting your resolve in your dbo.collection callback.

Comment: I've run the code through a beautifer for you.

Comment: @jas7457: Which one? It's a loop.

Comment: Why do you call `db.close()` in the middle of a loop.

Comment: The outer `for` loop will not await the callback at `.toArray()`. Where is `allhomework` defined? What is `i` within inner `for` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the best way to solve this would be to use the promise interface for your database and use `Promise.all()` to track when all the async database operations in your loop are done.  But, if you want to code it manually with your existing loop, you just have to keep a counter for when they are all done.

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let cntr = 10;
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        var query = {
            class: result[`class${i}`]
        };
        dbo.collection("homeworks").find(query).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                db.close();
                return reject(err);
            }
            for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                current = current + 1;
                console.log(current)
                allhomework[current] = result[i];
                console.log(allhomework[current])
            }
            --cntr;
            if (cntr === 0) {
               db.close();
               resolve(allHomework);
            }
        });
    }
    console.log("HOLA");
});
```

Other notes about this code:

I'm also wondering why there's a `db.close()` in the middle of your outer loop.  I would think that would cause a problem.

I also added a `reject(err)` to your `if (err)` check.

You have loop conflict with your `i` variable.  Put a `let` for each one to make them separate or change one of them to a different letter.

---

Here's a version that uses the promise interface in your database.  I was able to completely get rid of the inner loop and just let promises collect all the results in order for us.  Monbodb's `.toArray()` returns a promise that resolves with the query result if you don't pass it a callback.  We can use that with `Promise.all()` to collect all the results in order and to tell us when they are all done:

```
let promises = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let query = {
        class: result[`class${i}`]
    };
    promises.push(dbo.collection("homeworks").find(query).toArray());
}
Promise.all(promises).then(allResults => {
    // flatten the results into all one array - promises will have kept them in proper order
    db.close();
    let results = [].concat(...allResults);
    // now do whatever you want with the final array of results
}).catch(err => {
    db.close();
    // handle error here
});
```

Comment: I don't think the OP *wants* to do it manually - he just didn't know better. Would you mind posting a proper `Promise.all` solution?

Comment: Your method seemed to work. I'm guessing it was just resolving immediately. Also I'm not too sure why the `db.close` was there in the first place, I've moved it outside. Thank you!

Comment: @Bergi - will do in a bit.  Away from computer now.

Comment: @DanielGray - I added a much simpler version that uses the promises interface in mongodb.

Comment: @Bergi - Promise version added.